# How to print a row that contains specific values of a column?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

Im trying to make a loop and search a value in a column and then display the all the first row where is that value, i want to make it from 1950 to 2016

```
Em=
 year    x      y
 1950    5      3
 1950    4      3
 1950    2      4
 1950    1      5
 1951    6      7
 1951    5      6
 1951    1      4
 1951    0      3
```

I have been trying this:

```
for (p in 1:nrow(Em)){
if (Em[p,"year"]==1950)
   break
   print(Em[p,])} #it is not showing me just the first row that matches
{ else if (Em[p,"year"]==1951)
    break
    print(Em[p,])}
```

and obtain

```
year    x      y
1950    5      3
1951    6      7
```

Comment: missing `{` in if condition

Comment: missed another `}` for the loop

Comment: seems like you might want just `library(dplyr); Em %>% filter(year %in% 1950:1951)`

Comment: @RobJensen  `filter` returns all rows that where year == 1950 or 1951. OP wants the **first** row that matches 1950 and 1951

Comment: What about `subset(Em, Year == 1950 | Year == 1951)`

Comment: @LaMachineInfernale, this returns all records where year == 1950 or 1951. OP wants the **first** record that matches for each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with Base R:

```
Em_sub = aggregate(. ~ year, data = Em, '[', 1)
```

or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
Em_sub = Em %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  slice(1)
```

**Results:**

```
  year x y
1 1950 5 3
2 1951 6 7

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   year [2]
   year     x     y
  <int> <int> <int>
1  1950     5     3
2  1951     6     7
```

**Data:**

```
Em = read.table(text = "year    x      y
                1950    5      3
                1950    4      3
                1950    2      4
                1950    1      5
                1951    6      7
                1951    5      6
                1951    1      4
                1951    0      3", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Both solutions will return data.frames as shown in "Results", if you want a matrix, just use `as.matrix(Em_sub)`

Comment: useR, could you give me an advise about how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835464/how-to-manage-a-table-to-obtain-information-using-conditions

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base solution.

```
t(sapply(split(Em, Em$year), function(x) x[1, ]))
#      year x y
# 1950 1950 5 3
# 1951 1951 6 7
```

Briefly, we split the dataframe by year to create a list. The we iterate over the list and return the first row. Lastly, we transpose the resulting matrix so that it has the same orientation as `Em`