# How to manage a table/matrix to obtain information using conditions

Tags: r, matlab, conditional-statements

Ive been thinking about what is the best way to solve this, any advise?

The table/matrix X is:

```
X <- read.table(text = "    a       b       c       d       e
    0       27        0       28         8
    1       14       24       32        33
    0        4       22       25        27 
    0        3        7       26        34
    0       28       33       31        21
    0       16       17       24        18
    1        3       19        0        12
    0        2       23        5        24
    2       17       22       22        10
    0       35       15       17         2", 
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

or using matlab:

```
X =[
        0       27        0       28         8
        1       14       24       32        33
        0        4       22       25        27 
        0        3        7       26        34
        0       28       33       31        21
        0       16       17       24        18
        1        3       19        0        12
        0        2       23        5        24
        2       17       22       22        10
        0       35       15       17         2];
```

How could I obtain a table/matrix A and B which contains:

*rows and columns accumulated each 5 values until the maximum value of table X -> in this case: 0-5;0-10;0-15;0-20.. 0-35 (for both rows and columns).*

Table A:

The first thing is to select only the positive values of a, and then count the number of times these conditions occur:

1. The entry (1,1) of the table/matrix A would be the number of times the **b** values are among 0-5 and **d** values are among 0-5. The entry (2,1) would be the number of times the **b** values are among 0-5 and **d** values are among 0-10. The entry (3,1) would be the number of times the **b** values are among 0-5 and **d** values are among 0-15... this until the row is 0-35.
2. The entry (1,2) of the table/matrix A would be the number of times the **b** values are among 0-10 and **d** values are among 0-5. The entry (2,2) would be the number of times the **b** values are among 0-10 and **d** values are among 0-10. The entry (3,2) would be the number of times the **b** values are among 0-10 and **d** values are among 0-15... this until the row is 0-35.

*We form a 7x7 table/matrix, the results show this:*

```
   A:
          0-5     0-10     0-15     0-20     0-25     0-30     0-35
   0-5     1        1        1        1         1        1        1
   0-10    1        1        1        1         1        1        1
   0-15    1        1        1        1         1        1        1
   0-20    1        1        1        1         1        1        1
   0-25    1        1        1        2         2        2        2
   0-30    1        1        1        2         2        2        2
   0-35    1        1        2        3         3        3        3
```

*Where the columns are the intervals of b values and the rows the intervals for d values*

The meaning of the table/matrix A is the number of times the a values are higher than 0 and match different combinations intervals (each 5 values) among column b and d. **For example, for the entry (1,1) of result table A is 1 because in the row 7 of table X, there is only 1 number which a>0, b=3 (among 0-5) and d=0 (among 0-5)**. **Other example is the entry (7,4), which is 3 since there three times: a>0, b is among 0-20 and d is among 0-35**

The table/matrix B, would be the same table A but comparing columns c and e. B is:

```
  B:
          0-5     0-10     0-15     0-20     0-25     0-30     0-35
   0-5     1        1        1        1         1        1        1
   0-10    2        2        2        2         2        2        2
   0-15    2        2        2        2         2        2        2
   0-20    2        2        2        2         2        2        3
   0-25    2        2        2        4         4        4        5
   0-30    4        4        4        6         6        7        8
   0-35    4        4        5        7         7        9       10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I propose you under Matlab (it only takes care of creating the first table, but for the second one the code is basically the same):

```
% Define the sample data...
X = [
    0       27        0       28         8
    1       14       24       32        33
    0        4       22       25        27 
    0        3        7       26        34
    0       28       33       31        21
    0       16       17       24        18
    1        3       19        0        12
    0        2       23        5        24
    2       17       22       22        10
    0       35       15       17         2
];

% Find the upper bound (as a multiple of 5) and build the ranges...
X_max = max(max(X(:,2:end)));
X_upper = round(X_max / 5) * 5;

% Create the required ranges and their respective string representation...
R = 5:5:X_upper;
R_len = numel(R);
R_str = sprintfc('0-%d',R);

% Filter the table rows keeping only those with A > 0...
X = X(X(:,1) > 0,2:end);

% Apply the criterions to B and D (first and third rows)...
b = arrayfun(@(x) sum(X(:,1) > 0 & X(:,1) <= x),R).';
d = arrayfun(@(x) sum(X(:,3) > 0 & X(:,3) <= x),R);

% Cross the results of both computations into a single matrix...
A = num2cell(repmat(b,1,R_len) + repmat(d,R_len,1));
A = [[{''}; R_str.'] [R_str; A]];
```

The comments in the code should make everything pretty self-explanatory, but if you have any doubts feel free to ask for more details. For what concerns the type of the final result `A`, I opted for a matrix of cells, because table rows and columns are subject to strict naming conventions, but it's very easy to switch from this output to a table-based one... for example:

```
% Cross the results of both computations into a single table...
A = array2table(repmat(b,1,R_len) + repmat(d,R_len,1),'RowNames',R_str,'VariableNames',R_str);
```

**EDIT**

This code properly handles data as per OP requirements:

```
% Find the upper bound (as a multiple of 5) and build the ranges...
X_max = max(max(X(:,2:end)));
X_upper = round(X_max / 5) * 5;

% Create the required ranges and their respective string representation...
R = 5:5:X_upper;
R_len = numel(R);
R_str = sprintfc('R_0_%d',R);

% Adjust the range for exclusive limits and project it...
R(end) = R(end) + 1;
R_rep = [repelem(R,1,7).' repmat(R,1,7).'];

% Apply the criterions to B and D (first and third rows)...
X_a = X(X(:,1) > 0,2:end);
fun_A = arrayfun(@(b,d) sum(X_a(:,1) >= 0 & X_a(:,1) < b & X_a(:,3) >= 0 & X_a(:,3) < d),R_rep(:,1),R_rep(:,2));
A = array2table(reshape(fun_A,R_len,R_len),'RowNames',R_str,'VariableNames',R_str);

% Apply the criterions to C and E (second and fourth rows)...
X_na = X(X(:,1) >= 0,2:end);
fun_B = arrayfun(@(c,e) sum(X_na(:,2) >= 0 & X_na(:,2) < c & X_na(:,4) >= 0 & X_na(:,4) < e),R_rep(:,1),R_rep(:,2));
B = array2table(reshape(fun_B,R_len,R_len),'RowNames',R_str,'VariableNames',R_str);
```

Comment: Thanks Tommaso, could you explain me this part?:

`% Apply the criterions to B and D (first and third rows)...
b = arrayfun(@(x) sum(X(:,1) > 0 & X(:,1) <= x),R).';
d = arrayfun(@(x) sum(X(:,3) > 0 & X(:,3) <= x),R);`

im not sure the criterion is well applied

Comment: This is basically the part of the computation you are attempting to perform manually with R in your summarize functions... I perform an iteration on every upper bound of R and I calculate the occurrences in the vector. It's like an implicit for loop.

Comment: Yes, but I think the output is not correct because all the intervals are open on left side, and we only close the one who is **(0-35]** .. this is an excellent way to solve it, but i think this computations are not matching the real criterions. What do you think it could be the problem for the output is not correct?

Comment: `b values are among 0-5` translates into `[0 5]` in my mind. But actually it shouldn't be hard to change this small part of code...

Comment: Change `<=` to `<` and increase the last range by `1`.

Comment: Yeah its true, I already changed it.. but im not getting the same output I did manually counting, and manually doing with R-Code.. so im not sure what is doing wrong the code. Thanks anyway, your answer was awesome. If you find the mistake for why is it not doing the correct output please let me know. Best regards!

Comment: Is the expected output the one you are showing in your question?

Comment: Yes mr. Tommaso, and is the same I got on my manual code in R

Comment: Ok I found out. Actually the "error" comes from the fact you want both conditions to be respected at the same time, row-wise. Now the second script I posted handles this properly. I'm just wondering how you can retrieve that `B` as the correct result...

Comment: You are right. I typed the wrong table B. The code works PERFECT! that was amazing man. I really appreciate your help, it opened my mind a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code and it worked, but I would like to improve it in order to solve it in a more efficient way, and avoid it to be too tedious.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

B1 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B1=as.data.frame(t(B1))

B2 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B2=as.data.frame(t(B2))

B3 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B3=as.data.frame(t(B3))

B4 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B4=as.data.frame(t(B4))

B5 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B5=as.data.frame(t(B5))

B6 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B6=as.data.frame(t(B6))

B7 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 35) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 35) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a > 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B7=as.data.frame(t(B7))
Em=cbind(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7)
colnames(Em) =c('0-5','0-10','0-15','0-20','0-25','0-30','0-35')
```

For the second table:

```
B1 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 5) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B1=as.data.frame(t(B1))

B2 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 10) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B2=as.data.frame(t(B2))

B3 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 15) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B3=as.data.frame(t(B3))

B4 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 20) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B4=as.data.frame(t(B4))

B5 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 25) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B5=as.data.frame(t(B5))

B6 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b< 30) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B6=as.data.frame(t(B6))

B7 = A %>%
  summarise( i0_5 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d<  5) ),
             i0_10 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d< 10) ),
             i0_15 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d< 15) ),
             i0_20 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d< 20) ),
             i0_25 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d< 25) ),
             i0_30 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d< 30) ),
             i0_35 = sum( (a >= 0) & (b>= 0 & b<= 35) & (d >=0 & d<= 35) ) )

B7=as.data.frame(t(B7))

Em2=cbind(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7)
colnames(Em2) =c('0-5','0-10','0-15','0-20','0-25','0-30','0-35')
```